# How a database connection makes mysqli_real_escape_string more secure?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql

I am learning PHP+MySQL and observed that `mysqli_real_escape_string` function in PHP requires a identifier to a MySQL connection. From some research I found that it has something to do with charset and multibyte characters but I don't get it fully. So my question is how database connection helps in making mysqli_real_escape_string function more secure?

Comment: Connections can use different encodings. For some weird encodings, the standard escaping doesn't word.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>As a note, before I say anything about this issue: **please** consider moving towards MySQLi or PDO with parameterised queries. Not only are they an order or magnitude more secure, but they're easier to work with and fully supported. The old `mysql_` functions are now considered end-of-life and will soon be deprecated.</strike> (sorry, missed the tiny `i` from your original post... damn procedural calls!)

---

MySQL operates on strings. Strings are two things: a sequence of bytes, and a sequence of characters. The way that these two sequences map to each other is called a character set, which is specified by an encoding.

For example, ASCII maps letters, numbers, symbols, and control characters onto the byte values 0 to 127. Extended ASCII then adds more characters for the values 128 to 255. Other encodings, such as the UTF family (e.g. UTF-8) use single or multiple bytes to encode different characters. For example, UTF-16 characters can be encoded as either one or two 2-byte codepoints (i.e. each character is encoded as either 2 or 4 bytes).

The interesting part happens when you assume one character set or encoding, but the underlying data is actually encoded differently. For example, the East-Asian CJK character for "water" is 水, which is defined in UTF-16 as U+6C34. This encodes to `34 6C` in UTF-16LE. Now, if we accidentally assume that the data we were handed is ASCII, we'd decode this as "4l" rather than the proper Unicode character.

Now, what if your front-end application (in this case PHP) were configured to use Extended ASCII, but your database collation was set to UTF-8 (e.g. utf8_general_ci), and your user's machine was set up to use the Windows CP1251 Cyrillic codepage? In an ideal world, each system would recognise the requirements of the target application, and convert appropriately. Unfortunately this is not an ideal world. The underlying bytes representing Cyrillic characters would probably get garbled into ASCII characters on their way into the PHP webapp. Then any high characters (128-255) might re-map to different byte sequences when the ASCII characters are converted into UTF-8, or may even form entirely new characters if accidentally naively translated into UTF-8 codepoints. In some cases, there are special rules that cause certain sequential codepoints (e.g. diacritic marks) to get combined into special-form characters.

In short: **character encoding is voodoo**. This is serious "here be dragons" territory. If you can get a sane response from anyone who has written a real string library before (they usually just scrawl *"cthulhu ebcdic fhtagn"* on your face with a magic marker and walk away mysteriously) then they'll probably tell you some truly disgusting things about the abomination that is our human language.

Why does this matter for stuff like `mysql_escape_string`? Well, let's say your PHP app is UTF-8 mode, but your MySQL server is running in ASCII mode. Your user types a ∻ character ([U+223B](http://codepoints.net/U+223B)) and your escape function says "well shucks, that looks fine to me, I just care about quotes and stuff". Your MySQL server then looks at those underlying bytes... oh, it turns out that `22 3B` is an encoding of `";` in ASCII. Whoops!

This gets worse when you remember those combining tricks. You can do things like apply a diacritic mark to a piece of punctuation, or slap that punctuation in the middle of some Arabic text, and it could get combined into a "combined form" character with a totally different codepoint when it is re-encoded. This matters when you're using different modern encoding formats such as UTF-8 and UTF-16 together.

The `mysql_real_escape_string` function attempts to save us from this hell by properly checking the string once it has been re-encoded in the target MySQL server's selected encoding. It needs a reference to the connection in order to retrieve this metadata from the server.

---

<sub>*The most merciful thing in the world, I think, is the inability of the human mind to comprehend character encodings. We live on a placid island of ignorance in the midst of black seas of codepoints, and it was not meant that we should voyage far. The languages, each straining in its own direction, have hitherto harmed us little; but some day the piecing together of dissociated Unicode planes will open up such terrifying eccentricities of language, and of our frightful position therein, that we shall either segfault from the revelation or flee from the light into the peace and safety of EBCDIC.*</sub>

Comment: Please note that the OP is _asking_ about `mysqli_real_escape_string` and not `mysql_real_escape_string`. He's already using MySQLi

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't notice the 'i'. I blame procedural-style for looking weird.

Comment: Right with you on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping should be charset-aware, otherwise the escaping logic can be tricked into accepting illegal characters. To demonstrate this, you can use/abuse multi-byte characters in a charset-unaware escaping logic.

```
$user_input = "0xC8 ' EVIL_SQL--";
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($user_input);
$SqlQuery = "SELECT something FROM some_table WHERE one_thing = '$variable'";
```

Keeping in mind that the backslash is encoded as `0x5C` (one byte), our escape logic will try to escape that single-quote before the `EVIL_SQL`, so what will happen is that we'll have a byte `0xC8` followed by `0x5C`, which are two bytes represented as `0xC85C`, which is a valid mutli-byte character (I have no idea what it is).

The `0xC8` and the backslash have been merged together to make a new baby character. In other words, the backslash is gone and cannot escape our `'` anymore. So the final product is `"SOME_VALID_CHARACTER ' EVIL_SQL"` and the final SQL query becomes

```
"SELECT something FROM some_table WHERE one_thing = 'SOME_VALID_CHARACTER ' EVIL_SQL--'"
```

If our escaping were to be made aware of the encoding accepted on the server, some measures can be taken to combat such attacks.

More info: [MySQL announcement on the issue of multibyte SQL injection and the fix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-11.html)